# Almacenar el id de un elemento desde asp

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
<div><a href="Ciudad.aspx">
        <img src="images/Ciudades.jpg id="1" >
</a></div>
```

Esta imagen me redirecciona al darle clik, pero antes de eso quiero capturar su id para llevarla a la siguiente pagina. ¿Que medio ejecuto para esta situacion?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Ya que utilizas asp.net lo lógico es que utilices asp

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

De esta forma, puedes acceder a él desde el código trasero, por ejemplo en C#

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "images/Ciudades.jpg" // Asignas path de la foto
```

Luego puedes hacer lo que quieras. Leer el path, cambiarlo, pasarlo a una función, a una clase...